# .Net Core MVC postprocess Parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an query parameter in a number of controller actions that I would like to modify in a number of ways before using it.

e.g.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> GetFoo(string imageName)
{
    imageName = Uri.UnescapeDataString(imageName);
    imageName = RewriteSelfToUserId(imageName); // appends something to the string based on the currently logged in user
    .....
}
```

I would like to put all of this behaviour in one place, I am just unsure what the best way to do it is.

1. Using a class - not my favorite because I need some stuff from the request context which I would need to pass in.
2. Attribute on the string. Probably the same? How can I pass in the current User?
3. ???

Comment: You can pass in the user (or username) as part of the route parameters, directly from the view.

Comment: I am sorry, this is a rest api, so no view at all

Comment: A base controller class?

Comment: Do you want a solution to identify imageName in your query or do you want a solution for accessing the request before it reaches the action?

Comment: @Joshit i think the second probably

Comment: @ChristianSauer: Not the answer you´re looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class which inherits from `IActionFilter`:

```
public class MyFilter:IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // pre-processing here
        var queryArgs = context.HttpContext.Request.Query;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // post-processing here
    }
}
```

To register the filter, add this option in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new MyFilter()))
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

`OnActionExecuted` will be called before each `Action` and `OnActionExecuting` will be called after each `Action`.

Comment: As an additional ressource you can also look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406111/asp-net-core-ways-to-handle-custom-response-output-format-in-web-api/50564534#50564534